# using .where with .find

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am wondering how I can use `where cause with the ActiveRecord` find method.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Supplier.joins(:products).find(params[:id]).where('suppliers.permalink = ? AND variants.master = ?', params[:id], TRUE)
```

which gives me:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Supplier:0x007fe49b4eb330>
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Like, what are you trying to get from database? params[:id] is really a permalink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Supplier.joins(:products).find(params[:id]).where('suppliers.permalink = ? AND variants.master = ?', params[:id], TRUE)
```

What you're doing here is finding the first record with the id contained in `params[:id]`, then trying to run a `where` statement on that single record. `where` only works when run against the model itself.

The confusing part here is that you are using `params[:id]` both for the primary key ([find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) searches the id field) but then also comparing it to the `permalink` column in the where clause.

To explain the usage of both methods:

`find` will search for result(s) from the table, matching the argument you provide it to the `id` field. You can pass in multiple id's and this method is mostly used to select a row that you know exists, by id. Most commonly it is used with a single id and returns a single instance.

`where` is used to find all results from the table that match the clause and return a collection of records. You can then refine these results or select one, for example by using `.first`:

```
Supplier.joins(:products).where('suppliers.permalink = ? AND variants.master = ?', params[:permalink], true).first
```

(Note that you're using `joins(:products)` but then querying `variants` table. Is this incorrect?)

Comment: i reference the variants via the following `- @supplier.variants.each do |item|
        = render :partial => 'product', :locals => {:item => item }`

Answer (score -1):

```
Supplier.joins(:products).where('suppliers.permalink = ? AND variants.master = ?', params[:id], TRUE).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: this doesn't really return the sql i was expecting which is

`SELECT suppliers.id as supp_id, products.id as prod_id, products.name as prod_name, product_types.name as prod_type from suppliers
  INNER JOIN variant_suppliers on variant_suppliers.supplier_id = suppliers.id
  INNER JOIN variants on variants.id = variant_suppliers.variant_id
  INNER JOIN products on products.id = variants.product_id
  INNER JOIN product_types on product_types.id = products.product_type_id
WHERE suppliers.id in (1) and variants.master = TRUE`

Comment: as find executes the query, it will return the result set and not the query(which is present in the Active Relation object which we get by using where). If you need the SQL then you will need to use where. I am curious as to why would both be needed. You can use `where` with the same conditions you are using with `find`.